# How to modify my SQL to select values that match dates across different rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query (SQL Server):

```
select a.Booking_Type, b.Unit_Code, a.Start_Date, a.End_Date
from Booking a 
inner join Property b
on a.Property_ID = b.Property_ID 
where a.Agency_ID = 1020 and
b.IsEnabled = 1 and
a.Hold_Agreement_Signed is null and 
(convert(varchar(10), a.Start_Date, 102) = convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 102) or     convert(varchar(10), a.End_Date, 102) = convert(varchar(10), getdate()-1, 102))
```

my results from this query look like:

```
Booking_Type    Unit_Code   Start_Date             End_Date
0               448         2014-09-22 00:00:00    2014-09-28 00:00:00
0               448         2014-09-21 05:00:00    2014-09-21 05:00:00
0               K187        2014-09-19 00:00:00    2014-09-21 00:00:00
0               K187        2014-09-18 00:00:00    2014-09-21 00:00:00
```

What I am looking to get is a single row with Unit_Code = 448 because it has a row with a Start_Date of today and a row with an End_Date of yesterday (there was a checkout yesterday and a checkin today).

How do I modify my query to obtain this?

Comment: SQL Server.  Updated my question.

Comment: To me it looks like you want `max(start_date)` and `min(end_date)` `group by booking_type, unit_code`.  Its not very clear why you want to get those dates.

Comment: If you're using SQL Server 2012+, you can use the `LEAD()` and `LAG()` analytic functions.

Comment: So how do you want the result to look like?

Comment: Why are you converting your dates to strings?

Comment: I'm pretty much a novice when it comes to SQL.  Everything I have is essentially parsed together from other messages here or elsewhere.  Basically I don't know any better.

Comment: What do you want the single row for 448 to look like?

Comment: All I need returned is the Unit_Code that matches the start_date of today and the end_date of yesterday (across all the rows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to join a second instance of Booking:

```
select a.Booking_Type, b.Unit_Code, a.Start_Date, a.End_Date
from Booking  inner join Property b a.Property_ID = b.Property_ID 

inner join Booking  b1
on a.Property_ID = b1.Property_ID
```

and convert your where condition from  OR to AND

```
... convert(varchar(10), a.Start_Date, 102) = convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 102) 
**AND**   
convert(varchar(10), **B1**.End_Date, 102) = convert(varchar(10), getdate()-1, 102))
```

Comment: I'm told there is an incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where', using your sql.  Only I made it "Booking a" as it looks like that was a typo?

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to do it.

Comment: really glad i could help, oh right, i think once we introduce  "Booking b1" we will also have to give an alias to the first Booking instance, is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to return the `Unit_Code` that meets your date criteria, you should use `HAVING`:

```
select b.Unit_Code
from Booking a 
inner join Property b
   on a.Property_ID = b.Property_ID 
where a.Agency_ID = 1020 
  and b.IsEnabled = 1 
  and a.Hold_Agreement_Signed is null
GROUP BY b.Unit_Code
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN  CAST(a.Start_Date AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) THEN 1 END) = 1
   AND MAX(CASE WHEN  CAST(a.End_Date AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE()-1 AS DATE) THEN 1 END) = 1
```

Comment: @Jason Note that while the chosen answer works, adding another join to your query is expensive and not necessary.

Comment: I agree it is a more elegant/efficient solution to this problem. i might adapt this approach myself. it seems it could  bit more difficult to read its code and understand what was the intention though.